# How to copy backup WSB(Windows server 2012 R2) from VMware ESXi 6.5 to?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, esxi, windows-backup, dedicated-server

We have dedicated server(located in datacentre) which is installed with ESXI 6.5 and we create VM with Windows Server 2012 R2.
We are creating backups with Windows Server Backup feature and want to copy that to other destination.
Is it possible to be done or i have to choose other option like veeam backup?
I'm open for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking if you can export your VM and import it on another ESXi server?

Comment: The main question is the contents of generated Windows Server Backup how can be transferred to some cloud or other esxi, or  other possible way?